# Can I create interface for Android programmatically

Tags: java, android, interface

I'm learning about Android development, and I read that if you want to create an interface you need to use an XML file.

However, Android has classes in `android.views` and  `android.widgets`. Can I create the same interface programmatically? I don't want to know how, only if I can.

Comment: What, -1 without explanation, no more candies for this guy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Almost** all you can do by xml you can reproduce it programmatically.

This is the best resource you can read:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. Just look at the documentation :)

Comment: Ok, thanks, I start reading a book I'm and 2nd chapter and I want to know that before I finish the book :)

Comment: It's very easy to create the interface programmatically, but for some reason I find doing interface in XML more organized :)

Comment: Yes, but I was thinking about interface that is dynamic based on data or logic of the program.

Comment: You can then use `setContentView(R.layout.view)` after knowing, based on data, which layout you'll need.

Comment: I was talking about the case when interface is changing, like with application that build interface from Android device. If I will need to use `R` stuff, I will need to create xml file and compile it on runtime, which I think is impossible becasue I will need to have SDK on Andorid Device. But hopefully I can create it using normal way.